# Add Account token to routing

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'm trying to add an Account to the Silex route. My goal is to have routes like:

```
/{_account}/{_locale}/
/{_account}/{_locale}/products
/{_account}/{_locale}/block
```

You can find my Code [here on github](https://github.com/nilsleonhardt/silex-lab). It's a small sample. I can read the account token from the request and save the Account in the [AccountListener](https://github.com/nilsleonhardt/silex-lab/blob/master/src/SilexLab/Listener/AccountListener.php).

I try to handle the `_account` like `_locale`. Once set or updated the application don't have to bother about it. That means that the `_account` param will be set automatically if I call `$app['url_generator']->generate('blog')`.

This is my current problem. I don't know how to inform the UrlGenerator to set these param.

Maybe my approach is completely wrong.

I Hope you can send me some examples or Cookbooks or somethink. Or a merge  request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UrlGenerator uses parameters from the `request_context` (as you can see [in the code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.php#L161)) so you could set those in your listener.

<kbd>src/app.php</kbd>

```
$dispatcher = $app['dispatcher']->addSubscriber(
    new AccountListener(
        new AccountRepository(),
        $app['request_context'],
        $app['monolog']
    )
);
```

<kbd>SilexLab\Listener\AccountListener</kbd>

```
public function __construct(
    AccountProvider $accountProvider,
    RequestContext $requestContext,
    Logger $logger
) {
    //...
    $this->requestContext = $requestContext;
}

public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    //...

    $request->attributes->set('_account', $account);

    $this->requestContext->setParameter('_account', $account);
}
```